# MAMP can't load php_memcache.dll

Tags: php, memcached, mamp

I am using PHP 7.2.1 with MAMP PRO 4 on Windows 10.

When an exec() function in php handles large files (>100M), my code stops and I keep getting an internal server error (500). (Even though the exec() still continues and finishes in the background)

MAMP has logged them as

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_memcache.dll' (tried: C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.2.1\ext\php_memcache.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.
>   ), C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.2.1\ext\php_php_memcache.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.
>   )) in Unknown on line 0

(translated from Dutch).

Memcached is activated in MAMP

**C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.2.1\ext\php_memcache.dll** exists

and my php.ini contains **extension=php_memcache.dll**

---

FYI the exec is

```
exec('"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.exe" --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir "path/to/output" "path/to/input/presentation.pptx"');
```

and will continue its job even after the server error is displayed on screen. (the PDF is created without problems)

For smaller files there is no problem at all, and the rest of my PHP will execute as expected.

Comment: Isn't MAMP for the Mac?

Comment: interesting, its now on windows

Comment: @delboy1978uk MAMP for Windows has existed for years, and is already at version 4, as specified, so no, it's not just for Mac.

Comment: just find it funny, I mean the first M stands for Mac. I was about to say you had to enable `.so` files, not the `.dll`s, but then I saw your path and said "huh?"

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, I resolved it by doing the following

**go to C:\MAMP\bin\php**

select any folder having name php7.2.6 and above

copy the path name and set it in the enviroment variables

for me I chose 7.2.8
set this path C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.2.8 in enviroment variables